# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':sqflite:classpath'. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was installing the CachedNetworkImage and I get the following error:

A problem occurred configuring project ':sqflite'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':sqflite:classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
> Required by:
> project :sqflite
> > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> -Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> -Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':sqflite' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':sqflite' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

I would be very grateful for the help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you also show both your build.gradle files?

Comment: yes, its updated

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the 2nd `build.gradle` file inside the `android {}` block:

```
android {
    ...

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

    ...
}
```

Also in your `android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties`, change the `distributionUrl` to `https\://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip`